# Degenerate Two-Level Atom and Light Interaction

Tags: atomic-physics, quantum-optics

Assume that we have a degenerate two-level atom, (our atom has Zeeman sublevels), and then we have a light that has a polarization in specific direction for example x direction, now we have the interaction of light and our two level atom. so therefore my question is that in this process do we have some generated photons that they are squeezed and does their polarization is orthogonal to the polrization of our light ?

Comment: The two-level approximation is valid when the relevant light field is close to resonance, and there are no other energy levels close to the photon energy of the radiation. Saying that the two levels are degenerate is basically equivalent to saying that the two-level approximation is broken and you need to include more levels in your description.

Comment: so you mean that we have sort of multi-level atom, well, so in this situation, if we consider the interaction of our light with this atom, can this interaction produce squeezed state ?

Comment: That is too broad to be answerable.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty is right. You need the two levels to be non-degenerate to see any interaction with a photon field. Perhaps you meant there are 2 levels which are not degenerate and those levels have degenerate Zeeman sublevels?

Comment: @SabrinaChoice: Yes, i mean exactly Zeeman sublevels, i dont know how should i write the relevant formalism, you know i want to focus on the generation of photons that their polarization are normal to polarization of our source light, i need relevant formalism to consider the generation of photon with orthogonal polarization.